# installing ffmpeg on Mac fail

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I tried to install ffmpeg on Mac(macOS 10.13) with :  brew install ffmpeg

but I got below ....

```
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Error: ffmpeg: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source ffmpeg
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Comment: You can try to install from source with:
  `brew install --build-from-source ffmpeg`
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew presently carries bottles for macOS 10.14 *Mojave* and later.

You can try to install from source with:

```
 brew install --build-from-source ffmpeg
```

Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build failures with some formulae.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the binary file for Mac from this [link](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy and paste the following command in Terminal app:

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish. If you are prompted to enter a password, please type your Mac user's login password and press ENTER. Mind you, as you type your password, it won't be visible on your Terminal (for security reasons), but rest assured it will work.

2. Now, copy/paste and run this command to make brew command available inside the Terminal:
   `echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile`
3. Copy and paste the following command:
   `brew install ffmpeg`

Comment: Make sure your code is highlighted so that the format is clearer and better looking. Also you can improve the indentation to make it even prettier.

Comment: I tried highlighting it but its not allowing me

Comment: This was the only idea that worked for me.